# Find all files with specific name and move it two levels up from its location

Tags: linux, bash, file-management

I want to find all files with specific name "stdout.1.0", move it two/three levels up from its location. While moving it two/three levels up, I also want to rename it to "testjob.out".

All "stdout.1.0" files are located six levels down from parent directory.

```
./dirXXXXXX/dirXXXXXX/dirXXXXXX/dirXXXXXX/dirXXXXXX/dirXXXXXX/stdout.1.0
```

I used:

```
find . -type f -name stdout.1.0
```

and it outputs:

```
./dir100000/dir110000/dir111000/dir111100/dir111110/dir111111/stdout.1.0
./dir100000/dir110000/dir112000/dir111100/dir111110/dir111111/stdout.1.0
./dir100000/dir110000/dir113000/dir111100/dir111110/dir111111/stdout.1.0
./dir200000/dir210000/dir211000/dir211100/dir211110/dir211111/stdout.1.0
./dir200000/dir210000/dir212000/dir211100/dir211110/dir211111/stdout.1.0
./dir200000/dir210000/dir213000/dir211100/dir211110/dir211111/stdout.1.0
./dir300000/dir310000/dir311000/dir311100/dir311110/dir311111/stdout.1.0
./dir300000/dir310000/dir312000/dir311100/dir311110/dir311111/stdout.1.0
./dir300000/dir310000/dir313000/dir311100/dir311110/dir311111/stdout.1.0

.
.
./dirXXX000/dirXXX000/dirXXX000/dirXXX100/dirXXX110/dirXXX111/stdout.1.0
```

The directories above is just representative of where the file is, but there are multiple "stdout.1.0" files starting three levels down from parent directory.

Comment: _"moving it two/three levels up"_ How do you determine how many levels you need to move a file?

Comment: If the resulting file is always called _testjob.out_, what are you expecting if you find a stdout.1.0 in two different directories on the same depth in the directory tree?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a method in plain `bash` using `globstar` shell option , without using the `find`:

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s globstar
for file in **/stdout.1.0; do
    echo mv "$file" "${file%/*/*/*}/testjob.out"
done
```

Drop the `echo` if output looks fine.

Comment: Great answer. Here is the explanation what is happening:

https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Shopt-Builtin.html

Comment: For making it robust I would make sure that `$file` contains at least a slash (with `for file in ./**/stdout.1.0`), and use a relative path for going up the directories (with `mv "$file" "${file%/*}/../../testjob.out"`)

Answer (score 1):

You already know how to find them:

```
find . -type f -name stdout.1.0
```

Now, you need to move them to a higher directory (`..`) and rename them:

```
find . -type f -name stdout.1.0 -execdir mv {} ../../testjob.out \;
```

I would advise you to copy them first and remove later (use `cp` instead of `mv`): if anything goes wrong, you can get back easily to the current situation.

Comment: @Fravadona: you might be right. Do you know a solution? (Feel free to edit my answer)

Comment: Your command would work by replacing `-exec`  by `-execdir`.

Comment: @user1934428: Thanks for the advise, I've updated my answer accordingly.